# MSI GS63 7RD STEALTH NO WIFI

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, linux-mint, msi-laptop

My Wi-Fi suddenly disappeared, with only the airplane mode available in the respective menu.

I have tried

- reinstalling drivers
- uninstalling the device in device manager
- scanning for hardware changes
- etc...

Then suddenly I opened the computer and everything worked fine. After I turned it off it is again not working, and has not been ever since.

Deciding it was a good idea to switch operating systems to reset all possible software issues I installed Linux Mint 21.1. While the problem looks different, the situation is the same - No Wi-Fi. On Mint I only get the option of no Wired connection, and absolutely nothing regarding wireless. I can only manually create a network from the menu.

Comment: Given the tests you did, I suggest replacing the wireless card.

Comment: I thought all laptops had a key combination that toggled wifi?

Comment: I did try searching for one, and eventually ended up pressing all of them when neither of the online found combinations of Fn+function key worked, still nothing